# Config python script which knows its filename

Tags: python

I'd like to save complex configuration by writing some Python code with variable assignments and functions which I will import later by a ConfigReader class.

Basically so far I've written my config file:

```
a=1
```

And a class that works like

```
c=ConfigReader("C:\my_file")
print(c.a)
```

For that I used exec(), but now I also want that the config file knows its own filename (since the directory provides information for some variables)

So I need a config file like:

```
a=parse_project_number_from_dir(__file__)
```

It seems I need to replace exec() by some imp module loading in Python 3? Is that the easiest way to execute a simple file making it aware of its path?

Moreover I'd like my ConfigReader class to read all variables into a dictionary. (With exec I just looked at locals() ). What should I do now and can I not import the auxiliary imports in config file (like the parse_project_number_from_dir function), but just what I actually define there (i.e. a=)?

Comment: What problem do you really want to solve? Why not just import the files as a module?!

Comment: I want to import a configuration file which could be any file with Python code on the harddrive. I want the top level variables to be accessible. Incidently, the directory name that file is in maybe contain some information that I need to process in the configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

When you `exec` a Python script, there is no filename, because you are giving `exec` a string or a compiled object. The `exec` command has no way to know where you got this string.

But there is a way to share the knowledge with the config file that you are passing to `exec`. For example...

Let's say you have a config file that says

```
print myname
```

Then run the following Python script:

```
 ns = {}
 ns["myname"] = "sample.cfg"
 s = open("sample.cfg","r")
 exec s in ns # in 3.x use exec(s,ns) instead
```

This creates a new namespace, and in that namespace creates a variable named `myname`. Since the script knows the name of the file that it is about to open, it can assign this to a variable. The effect is the same as `exec 'myname = "sample.cfg"' in ns`.

Then, when you exec the config file, you share your script's knowledge by telling it to use the `ns` namespace. If this seems a bit confusing, do a little reading about `globals` and `locals` and namespaces.

Comment: That seems like a solution. But I wonder why I can't find exec with braces or the "in" statement in the documentation?!

Comment: `exec` is officially a Python statement like `def` or `class` so you need to look in the right place. I think there is a reference in the docs for the `eval()` function. And the braces are just making an empty `dict` which is how namespaces are stored.

Comment: I only find the exec *function* which is different since it accepts a string only. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: exec(s,ns) is the Python 3.x version of Python 2.x's exec statement

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"path to your file")
from yourFile import *
```